# Jenkins - Scripted Pipeline - Input String

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I am struggling to set up an input step in a **scripted** Jenkins pipeline that will let me as the user to input a string.

Scenario:
I am building a Docker image. I want to ask the user what tags to tag the image with once it's built. I want the user to supply a comma separated list like so:
latest,0.0.4,some-tag-name

All I have right now is an input asking the user if the core image should be built:

```
  def buildCoreImage = input(
    message: 'Build Core Image?',
    ok: 'Yes', 
    parameters: [
      booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: 'Push the button to build core image.',name: 'Yes?')
    ]
  )

  echo "Build core?:" + buildCoreImage
```

So in theory it should be as easy as changing the booleanParam to a stringParam, BUT the documentation does not have it:
[Jenkins - Pipeline: Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I found the answer:

```
  def coreImageTags = input(
    id: 'coreImageTags', message: 'Enter a comma separated list of additional tags for the image (0.0.1,some-tagname,etc):?', 
    parameters: [
      [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'None', description: 'List of tags', name: 'coreImageTagsList'],
    ]
  )

  echo ("Image tags: "+coreImageTags)
```

**Important note**

It is stated in the documentation but I want to point it out specifically: If you copy/paste my solution here, `coreImageTags` will contain a string directly. If you do multiple parameters like so:

```
    parameters: [
      [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'None', description: 'List of tags', name: 'coreImageTagsList'],
      [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'None', description: 'Something else', name: 'somethingElse'],
    ]
```

You will not get a single values but an array of values:

```
  echo ("Image tags: "+coreImageTags['coreImageTagsList'])
  echo ("Image tags: "+coreImageTags['somethingElse'])
```

The following posts will help:

[stackoverflow.com read-interactive-input-in-jenkins-pipeline-to-a-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080683/read-interactive-input-in-jenkins-pipeline-to-a-variable)

[CloudBees - Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204986450-Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs)

A list of classes you can use in this way and what they do is in the Jenkins Input-Step documentation:
[Pipeline - Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)